# How to get past 30 days records from table using timestamp column in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get past 30 days' records in SQL using the timestamp column, not the date column my query

```
SELECT sum(gasFeeInUSD) as total, STR_TO_DATE(created, '%Y-%m-%d') as t_date
FROM `transactions`
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(created, '%Y-%m-%d') >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND CURDATE()
GROUP BY DATE(STR_TO_DATE(created, '%Y-%m-%d'))
```

This query works fine with created column but I want to use it with the timestamp column.

Here is DB structure

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `transactions` (
  `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `transferType` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `from` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `to` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sendFrom` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sendTo` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `amount` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `currency` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `timestamp` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `othersNumioId` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `othersName` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `message` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `transactionHash` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `totalTokenAmountInUSD` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gasFeeInUSD` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `filterId` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `walletNo` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `import_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `day` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `month` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `year` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `modified` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
COMMIT;

-- Dumping data for table `transactions`


INSERT INTO `transactions` (`id`, `transferType`, `from`, `to`, `sendFrom`, `sendTo`, `amount`, `currency`, `id_`, `timestamp`, `othersNumioId`, `othersName`, `message`, `transactionHash`, `totalTokenAmountInUSD`, `gasFeeInUSD`, `filterId`, `status`, `walletNo`, `import_id`, `day`, `date`, `month`, `year`, `created`, `modified`) VALUES
(1, 'Send', '0x11F83064t5C59eBCDE1842FE28EB0ee6E77cbD3E', '0xFEe0F95a9AD7918A8trtc8F526d7a5315060050', 'Standard', 'Standard', 0.002263, 'ETH', '609212edbbe53e0019c78e42', '1621743092.497', 'timios1', 'Tim Allard', 'Hey', '0x8434d39cbe7db1afd95arta718881bbd78ccdf8684173a523b7ecd0afe3926e', '5.20462844', '1.69', '_1xdnjc6ja', 'Success', 't', 359, 'sun', '23', 'may', '2021', '2021-05-23 20:12:40', '2021-05-23 20:12:40'),
(2, 'Send', '0x22D227caCd975gAF0E326471976A818ef00F97889', '0x8b429171e521F2c83d6r4dAfe402fdB17eF3b3397B', 'Standard', 'Standard', 0.01, 'ETH', '609acbacde0cad0012e9afa7', '1621732567.403', 'timios', 'Tim Allard', 'Test from android how long can I make this message before it messes up the app?', '0xd1da2ef9e6ce3974746a40f242e22749fc4d27a1ed4e59340446da7ccf37e4b0', '23.5907', '1.68', '_dmzg4yswb', 'Success', 't', 358, 'sun', '23', 'may', '2021', '2021-05-23 20:12:40', '2021-05-23 20:12:40'),
(3, 'Internal Transfer', 'Numio Wallet', 'Standard Wallet', 'Numio', 'Standard', 10, 'USDC', '60a92c9d11afcse1200b257', '1621700163.749', NULL, NULL, NULL, 'sync-tx:e2878a8c3fad61057bdsd3e658d8e63f7b826e0d1b4c1d43b9ed113194367749', '9.991', '0.017', '_y2tn0rzjy', 'Success', NULL, 355, 'sat', '22', 'may', '2021', '2021-05-23 20:12:40', '2021-05-23 20:12:40'),
(4, 'Internal Transfer', 'Standard Wallet', 'Numio Wallet', 'Standard', 'Numio', 0.1, 'ETH', '60a92c9d11afdsdc0001200b257', '1621700005.226', NULL, NULL, NULL, '0x4b5350ddac9d6a1364986e49aa96522dsd321e1c42a64f38a765078add239dbc9af', '234.379', '7.83', '_tudolue4d', 'Success', NULL, 354, 'sat', '22', 'may', '2021', '2021-05-23 20:12:40', '2021-05-23 20:12:40'),
(5, 'Internal Transfer', 'Standard Wallet', 'Numio Wallet', 'Standard', 'Numio', 100, 'USDC', '60a92c9d11afdc0001200b257', '1621699943.112', NULL, NULL, NULL, '0xae27a438390esdd11f936a49dsbc1bf58a44b53cc00b27d8c84cfe0cb1ce2479c3276', '99.91', '21.82', '_vzvcawog0', 'Success', NULL, 353, 'sat', '22', 'may', '2021', '2021-05-23 20:12:40', '2021-05-23 20:12:40');
COMMIT;
```

Comment: What is the "timestamp" column?  Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: Also if you wish yo use something with something different from your current code, then please describe what was wrong with your attempts to adapt the code.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Basically response is coming from API and I am storing it to DB. this is the data that is coming from API `"timestamp": 1621743092497,` Now I want to get the last 30 days records based on this column

Comment: @astentx Created column is for when the record is inserted into DB not when this transaction was made. So timestamp gave me the date and time when this transaction was made. I want to show the last 30 days' transactions.

Comment: So please show the DDL of your table, because what is coming from *some* API and what is stored in *your* table are different things. The above number is definitely Unix timestamp, but the database itself has its own datatype for timestamp to encapsulate the representation and storage and provide convenient operations with timestamps

Comment: @astentx Here is the structure screenshot [https://snipboard.io/QGNE1x.jpg]

Comment: Please, paste the DDL, source data and desired output in text format so we are able to reproduce your problem. [Do not post images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question#285557)

Comment: Your `timestamp` is a `varchar(256)`... Why? Can you alter it to be a timestamp? It will make your life much simpler

Comment: @Ant I am storing timestamp value from API response. So I can't change it to timestamp

Comment: @astentx I have added a table structure. and insert records

Comment: The api you use responds with a unix timestamp, which you can convert to mysql's timestamp before the insertion. You can also convert it from unixtimestamp with `FROM_UNIXTIMESTAMP`([examples](https://database.guide/from_unixtime-examples-mysql/)) and compare that to your interval

Comment: Just to observe, it's fantastically rare that columns called 'amount' (when succeeded by columns called 'currency') are `float`; it's rather why `DECIMAL` was invented

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what I'm guessing is correct, your `varchar(256)` `timestamp` stores a Unix Timestamp in milliseconds, you need only convert it after dividing it by 10000, like so:

```
WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp / 1000) >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 30 DAY
```

Or you could convert the right part of the equation:

```
WHERE (timestamp / 1000) >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 30 DAY)
```

Plus I think you may want to switch `CURRENT_DATE` to `CURRENT_TIME`

Comment: it returns data of 15 apr. which is wrong

Comment: If Gordon Linoff is correct, and your timestamps are in ms, you need to divide by 1000 your timestamp. I added that in my answer, check it

Comment: Great! And since you are new, may I suggest you upvote the comments and answers that helped you figure it out, as well as accepting either mine or Gordon's answer?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded.
this is an error while upvote

Answer (score 0):

Your timestamp is looks like a type of Unix timestamp measured in milliseconds since 1970-01-01.

If you want exactly 30 days before the timestamp, just use arithmetic:

```
where timestamp < (unix_timestamp() * 1000) - (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
```

Comment: #1305 - FUNCTION dashboard_dev.unixtime does not exist

Comment: @kashanilyas . . . MySQL has inconsistent naming for these functions.  `from_unixtime()` but `unix_timestamp()`.  I fixed the answer.

Comment: GROUP BY FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp) Is this works also?

Comment: @kashanilyas . . . Yes, if you want to summarize the data that way.  However, it is functionally equivalent to `GROUP BY timestamp`.  Well, one caution, with your timestamps, you need `from_unixtime(timestamp / 1000)` because yours are measured in milliseconds.

Comment: Will you please share query for it.